# App is displaying wrong time on server but correct time on localhost?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, momentjs

My app basically sends out an email for a scheduled appointment with a start date and end date. On my local machine that is using Windows OS, it's sending out the correct time but on my ec2 ubuntu Linux server on AWS it is not and I'm not sure why...

An example that is displaying the wrong time is an appointment that is between 10:00AM - 10:30AM and this works fine on my localhost but when I `console.log` the start and end time it's displaying 5:00PM instead..

My Code below is exactly the same for localhost and what I pushed to my ubuntu Linux server but they're displaying different times.

What I want is to basically have that ISO 8601 time display correctly which is currently 10:00AM my time like on my localhost machine.

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");
var MetaTags = require("./metaTags");
var fs = require("fs");
const router = express.Router();
// loads .env file
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const Moment = require("moment-timezone");

const config = dotenv.config({ path: path.join(__dirname, "../config/.env") });

// ISO 8601 Format
const randomDate = new Date("2021-03-27T17:00:00.000Z");

const correctDate = Moment(randomDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:ss A");

console.log("another date format is", correctDate);
// Logs 03/27/2021 10:00AM for start date... This is the correct time I want it to log like on my ubuntu Linux server...
```

What localhost is logging for the time:

[image]

What my ubuntu Linux server is logging for the time:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try running date command directly in linux terminal to see what time the server is displaying, maybe you need to verify that both machines have the same time zone.

Comment: I ran the `date` command and it's displaying Sat Mar 27 04:10:10 UTC 2021 while on my localhost Windows OS machine it's displaying 9:10pm. Does that mean I need to change my linux time to match what is on my Windows OS machine?

Comment: Yes, if your servers have different time zone configured, then it is expected behavior, check what windows time zone is set on windows and verify on linux as well, adjust one, or add the logic in your code to make the conversion if you needed.
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-or-change-timezone-in-linux/